# google map does not reload when I click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map as follow :

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'zoom': 3, 'disableDefaultUI': true }).bind('init', function (evt, map) {


         var bounds = map.getBounds();

         var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
         var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
         var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
         var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
         for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

             var contentString = 'load';
             $(this).gmap('addMarker',
        { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(
           southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
           southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random()),
            'content': contentString
        }
      ).click(function (i) {
          $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
              content: this.content
          }, this);
      });
         }
         $(this).gmap('set', 'MarkerClusterer', new MarkerClusterer(map, $(this).gmap('get', 'markers')));
     });
 }).load();
```

at loading time it is good but when I for example call the function maptest() below again by for example clicking on a button the map does not change at all even I unbind the map and bind it again but no effect:

```
function maptest(){


 demo.add(function () {
     $('#map_canvas').unbind("init");
     $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'zoom': 3, 'disableDefaultUI': true }).bind('init', function (evt, map) {


         var bounds = map.getBounds();

         var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
         var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
         var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
         var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
         for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

             var contentString = 'test';
             $(this).gmap('addMarker',
        { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(
           southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
           southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random()),
            'content': contentString
        }
      ).click(function (i) {
          $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
              content: this.content
          }, this);
      });
         }
         $(this).gmap('set', 'MarkerClusterer', new MarkerClusterer(map, $(this).gmap('get', 'markers')));
     });
 }).load();
```

}

**Update : Also when I use $('#map_canvas').gmap('destroy').gmap... instead the map reloads but I get alarm box which sais: unable to load due to either poor internet connection or some cdn are not responsive as we would like them....**

Please help I am so confused? what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may work in this way:

```
 $('#map_canvas').gmap('destroy');
 $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'zoom': 3, 'disableDefaultUI': true }).bind('init', function (evt, map) {
```